# A continuous function on a compact set is bounded and attains a maximum and minimum: "complex version" of the extreme value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, compactness, extreme-value-theorem

My textbook, *Complex Analysis*, by Shakarchi and Stein, gives the following theorem:

> **Theorem 2.1** *A continuous function on a compact set $\Omega$ is bounded and attains a maximum and minimum on $\Omega$*.
>
> This is of course analogous to the situation of functions of a real variable, and we shall not repeat the simple proof here.

I was trying to find the real and complex proofs for this, but I'm not completely sure what the theorem is.

I thought it looked similar to the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem):

> If a real-valued function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ must attain a maximum and a minimum, each at least once.

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space) for compact spaces describes them as follows:

> In mathematics, more specifically in general topology, **compactness** is a property that generalizes the notion of a subset of Euclidean space being closed (i.e., containing all its limit points) and bounded (i.e., having all its points lie within some fixed distance of each other).

**EDIT:** As can be seen in the comments, there is some confusion as to whether what I had originally written here makes sense. Under the impression that what I had originally written was incoherent, I made an edit that rewrote this section in such a way that I thought might make more sense. However, based on  MoonLightSyzygy's comment, it seems that what I had originally written might have been fine. So what I'm going to do is include both versions of this section, so that someone may give a more definitive answer as to which is (the most) coherent. As you can see, I am a novice in the area of mathematical analysis, so I apologise for any confusion.

---

**Version 1:**

Given this definition of compactness, it seems to me that such a real-valued function is indeed compact. My understanding is that real-valued functions are indeed subsets of Euclidean space (it is my understanding that they are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$). Furthermore, since the real-valued function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$, it is by definition both closed and bounded. Therefore, such a real-values function satisfies all of the conditions necessary for compactness.

---

**Version 2:**

Given this definition of compactness, it seems to me that the domain of such a real-valued function is indeed compact (if I'm understanding this correctly, the requirement is that the *domain* of the function be compact, right?). My understanding is that the domains of such real-valued functions are indeed subsets of Euclidean space (it is my understanding that the domains of real-valued functions are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$). Furthermore, since the real-valued function $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$, it is by definition both closed and bounded. Therefore, such a real-values function satisfies all of the conditions necessary for compactness.

---

Is what I've written here correct? Am I misunderstanding anything?

Is the textbook's theorem the "complex version" of the extreme value theorem? If not, then what are the theorems in question that I am seeking?

And as an aside, is it the case that *all* real-valued functions are compact? It seems to me that this is clearly **not** the case, but I would just like to confirm.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: What do you mean by "a real-valued function is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$"?

Comment: @Nick Sorry, you're right, that doesn't make sense. I will make an edit.

Comment: @Nick So, my understanding is that to say that a function is "on a set" means that the set in question is the domain of the function, correct? That's what I'm attempting to describe.

Comment: Functions are sets of pairs. So, saying that a real function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ makes perfect sense, by viewing elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}$ as elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Are you saying that the description I made in my post is coherent? Or are you saying the contrary?

Comment: I am saying that the question that Nick asked has the answer I gave above, instead of 'that doesn't make sense'. I haven't read you question. The post is too long for me.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Oh, no, what I meant was that *my* work is what didn't make sense; hence why I said that I would make edits.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Ok, it seems that you're saying is that what I had  written previously *did* make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are greatly over complicating the statement; take a step back.

A complex number can be written as $z=x+iy$ and a complex function with complex output is given by $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y),$ where $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, $v:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Note that if $v(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y),$ then $f$ is just real-valued.

The magnitude (or modulus) is given by $|f(z)|=\sqrt{[u(x,y)]^2 + [v(x,y)]^2},$ which is a real number. Show that the function $(x,y)\mapsto\sqrt{[u(x,y)]^2 + [v(x,y)]^2}$ is continuous, which is true since $f$ is continuous.

If all $(x,y)\in K,$ where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you can just apply the extreme value theorem from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}.$ Somewhere in $K$, $|f(z)|$ has maximum modulus.

Comment: Ahh, great answer! Thank you very much! Sorry about the confusion; trying to self-study mathematical analysis often leads to situations where I overcomplicate things in my effort to gain a rigorous understanding. At least I know that I was on the right track with regards to the extreme value theorem.

Comment: Believe me - as someone who has done a lot of self-studying, I completely understand. Asking subtle questions will make you much better in the long run.